# How to Record Starting Question in Spark AR

Tags: spark-ar-studio

Currently, when you hit the record button, it fires the pulse which starts recording the answer, not the question. What do I need to do to start recording the question first and then delay start of the answer by a number of seconds?

[image: logic]

Answer (score 0):

Adding a delay allows the camera to start before firing the pulse

[image: fixed]